# Aggregation based on two fields in Elasticsearch results in SearchParseExcepetion with "cannot find aggregator type"

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am using Elasticsearch **1.4.0** and trying out the aggregation feature. I keep getting a SearchParseException with the message `Cannot find aggregator type [fieldName] in [aggregationName]`.

In JSON format, my data looks like the following.

```
{ "userCode": "abcd123", "response": 1 }
{ "userCode": "abcd123", "response": 1 }
{ "userCode": "abcd123", "response": 0 }
{ "userCode": "wxyz123", "response": 0 }
{ "userCode": "wxyz123", "response": 0 }
{ "userCode": "wxyz123", "response": 1 }
```

Note, there are 2 users, `abcd123` and `wxyz123`, and I simply want to count the number of times each responded 1 and 0. If I put this data into a SQL table, in SQL select syntax, I would do something like this (if this SQL example helps to illustrate what I am trying to do).

```
select userCode, response, count(*) as total
from response_table
group by userCode, response
```

I would expect a results set that looks like the following.

```
abcd123, 0, 1 //user abcd123 responded 0 once
abcd123, 1, 2 //user abcd123 responded 1 twice
wxyz123, 0, 2 //user wxyz123 responded 0 twice
wxyz123, 1, 1 //user wxyz123 responded 1 once
```

For Elasticsearch, my aggregation JSON looks like the following.

```
{
 "aggs": {
  "users": {
   "terms": { "field": "userCode" },
   "aggs": {
    "responses" : {
     "terms": { "field": "response" }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

However, I get the SearchParseException: `Cannot find aggregator type [responses] in [aggs]`. What am I doing wrong?

If it helps, my mapping file is very simple, and looks like the following.

```
{
  "data": {
    "properties": {
      "userCode": {
        "type": "string",
        "store": "yes",
        "index": "analyzed",
        "term_vector": "no"
      },
      "response": {
        "type": "integer",
        "store": "yes",
        "index": "analyzed",
        "term_vector": "yes"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted (including mappings, actual data) works for me. In 1.4.0.

Answer (score 2):

The following aggregation worked for me (it got me the results I wanted), but I'd still like for some clarifications on why my previous approach resulted in a SearchParseException.

```
{
 "aggs": {
  "users": {
   "terms": { "field" : "userCode" },
   "aggs": {
    "responses": {
     "histogram": { "field": "response", "interval": 1 }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I misread the documentation and thought the nested `aggs` was a child of the root `aggs`, when it is actually part of the group (which was also your original mistake). Thanks for posting this, I was going nuts, certain I was doing everything right.